# Angular2 Http POST throws Subscriber Exception

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I have the following files in an Angular 2 app:

**Injectable service**

```
@Injectable()  
export class CompanyService{
    constructor(private http:Http){}

    public test():any{
        return this.http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/blah')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'company.html',
    providers: [CompanyService]
})
export class CompanyPage{
    constructor(private companyServ:CompanyService){}

    //This method is used from a submit for using ngSubmit
    public onSubmit():void{
        this.companyServ.test().subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Data', data);
        }, err => {
            console.error('Error', err);
        }, console.log('End'));
    }
}
```

When the view is rendered and method `onSubmit` is called, I get the following error:

[image: Error when "onSubmit" method is called]

Any information about the error would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the data type that returns the `test()` method of class `CompanyService`:

**Injectable service**

```
public test():Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/title/ipsum/content/blah')
           .map(res => res.json())
           .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

**Component**

I deleted the 3 parameter because `Observable<any>` allows only 2 parameters: The success function and the error function

```
public onSubmit():void{
    this.companyServ.test().subscribe(data => {
        console.log('Data', data);
    }, err => {
        console.error('Error', err);
    });
}
```